# Render cshtml in razor component

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a some partial cshtml-views. This views inherits from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.

I want to render this views in blazor component (inherits from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase).

In cshtml it possible with @Html.Partial(...), but in the blazor component @Html is not available.

Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Blazor, you can get equivalent functionality of `@Html.Partial` or `@Html.PartialAsync` by loading the HTML as a string and then casting it to [MarkupString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.markupstring?view=aspnetcore-7.0) as it has an [explicit cast operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.markupstring.op_explicit?view=aspnetcore-3.1) since ASP.NET Core 3.1.:

```
@code 
{
    string anchorHtmlString = "<a class='btn btn-primary'>Click me!</a>";
}

@((MarkupString)anchorHtmlString)
```

Note the cast expressions is wrapped inside `@()`.

And the string itself can be loaded by another async HTTP request inside [OnInitializedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#component-initialization-oninitializedasync).

```
string anchorHtmlString = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync("request/url");
```